# I Want To add FileFilter ("*.doc") to save automatic file without type extension

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

I want to add my FileFilter in as3. Because there is the main problem of extension typing. I already use this option

(saveFile.save(bytes,_dbookNameFill+".doc"));

but I want to automatically generate this extension when I save my file any names. Please Help Me I am Mini Programmer.

```
var bytes:ByteArray = document.save(Method.LOCAL);
var saveFile:FileReference = new FileReference()
var _dbookNameFill:String = 
QSTPreviwForStudentMC._bookNameMc.bookNtxt.text;
var fileFilter:FileFilter=new FileFilter("*.doc","*.text;*.RTF;");
saveFile.save(bytes,_dbookNameFill+".doc");
```

Comment: _**"There is the main problem of extension typing"**_ what is the problem with typing??... You say _**"I want to automatically generate this extension when I save my file"**_ well doesn't this code `_dbookNameFill+".doc"` actually do that? Your code generates a filename with extension, so what is the problem?? Explain better because we can't see your computer. You want to save auto without the "Save file" pop-up?

Comment: Other Software doesn't Require to type file extension. they automatic fill that is the feature of the software.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this won't work. Using AS3's FileFilter class you're just able to limit
what's being displayed on a file dialog you've opened using Filereference.browse().
FileReference.save() isn't affected by a FileFilter and as far as I know there is
no way to force a particular file extension - perhaps due to security reasons.